# bootstrap not working when I download with bower in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, asp.net-core-1.0

I am going through the Sports Store application in the Pro ASP.Net Core MVC book by Adam Freeman. In chapter 8 near the end he starts adding in some styles with bootstrap.

Step 1: Add bower.json file and add the bootstrap dependency:

```
{
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  }
}
```

Step 2: Add this line to you layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css" />
```

Now the entire layout code looks like this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css" />
    <title>SportsStore</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row panel">
        <div id="categories" class="col-xs-3">
            Put something useful here later
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if I inspect the html I can see the bootstap files being pulled in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

So now at this point if I run the code I should see a black nav bar with the SPORTS STORE title in white all with bootstrap navbar styles.
Also with in render body there is a forlooped list of products that show in a bootstrap well style.

And the usual left margin is not working.

Cannot get the bootstrap styles to take affect.

Anyone have any ideas why this is so tough to get bootstrap to take affect?

UPDATE 1:
Well I think fooling around I changed the dependency to 3.3.6.
It doesn't clean up 3.3.7 so I have both folders:

1) www/lib/bootstrap.

2) www/lib/bootstrap-css

If I point to bootstrap-css everything seems to work.

This is pretty much how it has gone in my own projects.
I can use bower for pretty much any dependency like angular. 
But I have trouble with bootstrap.

Basically I have been downloading an older version of bootstrap before the new arrangement of files and manually putting under www/lib/bootstrap.

I am pretty bad and ignorant at client side tools and building client side libraries and such.
Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Bootstrap while coding this app from "Pro ASP.Net Core MVC" book. My solution was replacing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css" />
```

With this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In the *_Layout.cshtml* file.

Please notice that it is not the newest version. I used the same version (3.3.6) that is in the book to make app look exactly the same as in the book.